# GCC/MinGW not installing correctly on Cygwin?

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I can't find the as.exe executable which comes with the MinGW runtime.

Here is what I checked in Cygwin: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uogW.png

I did a search using Search Everything and the Windows search tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ type as
 as is hashed (/usr/bin/as)

 $ uname -r
 1.7.27(0.271/5/3)
```

Default installation. 
I think we need more information about your cygwin version.